# Android random Settings option

Tags: android

[This](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19348704/Screenshot_2013-12-14-02-24-51.png) settings menu item appears when I press the hardware settings key in my app. I have not added it but it's just there. How can I utilize it so when I press it would open up an activity of my choice/or how can I remove it? I saw that it's connected to a variable in `res/values/strings` named `action_settings` but i couldn't find where it's used.

Comment: nothing is "just there" in android.

Comment: Well if I didn't put it there for me it's JUST there.

Comment: its there as its part of the default application template in eclipse and android studio. or the IDE you are using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is you are working with a template generated by Eclipse or some other IDE. In that case, you are seeing the overflow for the action bar. That is configured via `onCreateOptionsMenu()` and `onOptionsItemSelected()`, usually by means of a menu resource (`res/menu/`). You can read more about this in [the documentation for the action bar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionItems).